# Passing new data to an asynchronous, threaded function that may still be using the old data

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, class, asynchronous

I am having some problem related to C/C++:
Suppose I have some class

```
class Demo
{
   int constant;
   public:
    void setConstant(int value)
    {
        constant=value;
    }
    void submitTask()
    {
       // need to make a call to C-based runtime system to submit a 
       // task which will be   executed "asynchronously"
       submitTask((void *)&constant);
    }
};

// runtime system will call this method when task will be executed
void func(void *arg)
{
    int constant= *((int *)arg);
    // Read this constant value but don't modify here....
}
```

Now in my application, I do something like this:

```
int main()
{
  ...
  Demo objDemo;
  for(...)
  {
     objDemo.setConstant(<somevalue>);
     objDemo.submitTask();
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, hopefully you see the problem as tasks should read the value set immediately before a asynchronous call . As task calls are asynchronous so a task can read wrong value and sometimes results in unexpected behavior.

I don't want to enforce synchronous task execution just because of this constraint. The number of tasks created are not known in advance. I just need to pass this simple integer constant in an elegant way that will work with asynchronous. Obviously I cannot change the runtime behavior (mean that signature of this method `void func(void *arg)` is fixed).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to wait for the C code to finish before you make the next call then you can't reuse the same memory location over and over.  Instead, create an array and then pass those locations.  For this code, I'm going to assume that the number of times the for loop will run is n.  This doesn't have to be known until it's time for the for loop to run.

```
int* values = new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    values[i] = <somevalue>;
    submitTask((void*)&values[i]);
}
```

At some later point when you're sure it's all done, then call

```
delete[] values;
```

Or, alternately, instead of an array of ints, create an array of Demo objects.

```
Demo demo[] = new Demo[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    demo[i].setConstant(<somevalue>);
    demo[i].submitTask();
}
```

But the first makes more sense to me as the Demo object doesn't really seem to do anything worthwhile.  But you may have left out methods and members not relevant to the question, so that could change which option is best.  Regardless, the point is that you need separate memory locations for separate values if you don't know when they're going to get used and don't want to wait.

Comment: +1: but in C++ is `int *values = new int[n];` and `delete[] values;` or, even better, `std::vector<int> values(n);`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do both of your proposed solution as my interface is actually a library interface and I don't want to modify that also. The only possibility I see is creating a new memory inside method submitTask like "new int()" and then using it. Obviously it will cause problem with memory leakage but that is only visible way, I guess.

Comment: You can avoid the memory leakage if you keep track of the addresses and then delete them later.  You could just create a Vector<int*> and add the addresses to them as you create them.  Later you can go through the Vector calling delete on the addresses and then removing them from the Vector.

Comment: @6502: Thanks for the corrections.  I have included them.  Although I love the STL, in this case I don't think that a vector would really add much since the size should be known before the loop is run.  If it were a while loop instead of for, I would definitely go with the vector so that we wouldn't need to know the size a priori.

Comment: The main feature of a vector would be that in case of an exception no memory leak occurs. However in this case the handling of an exception is even more delicate given that some threads could have already been started.